# Delphi Tokyo 10.2.2 Project Application Icon Settings raise exception

Tags: delphi

I am having problem with setting project option in Tokyo 10.2.2. I tried also re-install it but same error appears. Please see the attached images.

[image: raised exception when click on project->option menu item]

[image: win32 default icon is missing]

How to solve it?

Comment: By pressing _Default_ button, saving project settings and rebuilding project?

Comment: same first image exception raised. Also I can't load Icon.

Comment: Which icon does not load?

Comment: I can't load any win32 icon on application settings including the default one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If any one has this problem, all you have to uninstall with remove registry settings and re-install.